# MongoDB compound index order of the fields

Tags: mongodb

I have collection schema

1) user
2) age
3) role

I have created compound index ( `{ age: 1, user: 1 }` ). When I find documents with criteria `{ age: { $gt: 21, $lt: 50 }, user: 'user124' }`, the index is properly used ( I am watching in `explain()`), but when I change order to `{ user: '124', age: { $gt: 21, $lt: 50 } }` results and index usage is identical. When I have compound index on two fields, order in criteria doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes, order in criteria does not matter, order of index does though

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, the order does not matter.

In fact, only arrays in the query are ordered and dictionarys are not.

http://json.org/